# Как в цикле динамически менять название листов

Tags: java, циклы, list

```
 for(int i =0; i < size; i++)
            {
                List<String> s = sourceList.subList(s,t);
            }
```

> Хочу чтобы в этом месте List s создавались файлы s+i (s1,s2 и т.п.).

Comment: А вопрос в чем? Как массив списков создать?

Comment: не , Вопрос в том как к названию s подписывать цифру i. s+i не работает

Comment: В такой постановке, ответ никак. Но оно вам и н надо.

Comment: а если мне нужно несколько листов создавать... но сколько именно определяет параметр size... как мне эту проблему решить?

Comment: Я вроде бы сразу написал, массив листов. ArrayList<List<String>>

Comment: а....ну да. Спасибо))

Comment: @pavel, ввы б в ответ это написали - вполне нормальная ошибка для новичка - пытаться динамически создавать имена для переменных

Answer (score 1):

В java, как и почти во всех языках со статический типизацией подобное невозможно. Но вам не нужны переменные s1, s2, s3...
Вы можете создать массив переменных любого типа (даже типа массив). В Java это может ввглядеть примерно так: `ArrayList<List<String>> s = new ArrayList<>();` дальше `s.add(sourceList.subList(i*10,(i+1)*10))` Константы взял из вашего предыдущего  вопроса.